# Socket.IO doesn't work externally

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

## Node.js Server

```
var app = require ('express')();
var http = require ('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var users=0;
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    users++;
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
     });
     socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        users--;
        console.log('user disconnected');
      });
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

http://localhost:3000 it can hold index.html and works well

but  http://104.155.198.127:3000 it responds (This site can't be reached)
104.155.198.127 is real ip

Comment: That IP only has the 3389/tcp port externally opened. May you check your firewall?

Also, may you try curl http://127.0.0.1:3000 on your server console?

Comment: now 3000 is open and http://127.0.0.1:3000 responds correctly. but externally doesn't work

Comment: Still not opened. Do `nmap 104.155.198.127` to list the opened ports... May you check your provider's firewall?